# How to use middy middleware on a function in a test file?

Tags: node.js, middy

I am writing a test file in nodejs using sinon and need to use middleware in a function call which looks like below.

baseHandler.js

```
exports.baseHandler=async()=>{
  // some code
}
```

baseHandlerTest.js

```
const app = require('../../main/baseHandler');
const handler=middy(app.baseHandler).use(validator(validatorSchema)); //this doesn't seem to work
const response = await handler(event, null, null, getDnisConfig, toResponse, null);
```

Error

```
callback is not a function
```

What changes I need to make in above Test file so that when `app.baseHandler` is called, the middleware kicks in the validation ?

Answer (score 0):

middy is full of test examples within its codebase.

Here is a sample that should get you started.

```js
const test = require('ava')
const middy = require('../../core/index.js')
const validator = require('../index.js')

test('It should validate response', async (t) => {
  const event = {}
  const expectedResponse = {
    body: 'Hello world',
    statusCode: 200
  }

  const handler = middy((event, context) => {
    return expectedResponse
  })

  const schema = {
    type: 'object',
    required: ['body', 'statusCode'],
    properties: {
      body: {
        type: 'string'
      },
      statusCode: {
        type: 'number'
      }
    }
  }

  handler.use(validator({ outputSchema: schema }))

  const response = await handler(event)

  t.deepEqual(response, expectedResponse)
})
```

You may want to also check that `validatorSchema` is the correct structure.